# How to use milliseconds instead of microsenconds in datetime python

Tags: python, datetime

A client has specified that they use DateTime to store their dates using the format `2021-06-22T11:17:09.465Z`, and so far I've been able only to obtain it in string dates, because If I want to maintain the milliseconds it saves them like `2021-06-22T11:17:09.465000`.

Is there any possible way to force DateTime to use milliseconds instead of microseconds? I'm aware of the `%f` for microseconds in the format, but I've tried everything I can think of to reduce those 3 decimals while keeping it DateTime with no results however.

Comment: As I see your comment at different answer you need to show what you've tried thus-far because there is a lot of confusion. End of Review.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use the timespec parameter, as described in python docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now().isoformat(timespec='minutes')   
'2002-12-25T00:00'
>>> dt = datetime(2015, 1, 1, 12, 30, 59, 0)
>>> datetime.now().isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')
'2021-12-02T14:03:57.937'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately isoformat returns a string, and I need a full datetime object

Comment: I am confused. Using a datetime object you can get the iso representation with any precision you need. Are you talking about parsing a string into a datetime object?

Comment: @JavierRomero. - Generally, you'd use `datetime` for internal representation, with microseconds (including the extra `000`); and the required format for input and output, as strings, with the required precision

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're looking for this? See also my general comment at question.

The variable 3 in `[:3]` can be adjusted to your liking for amount of zeros in ms to ns range. Use the `type()` to show you its a DateTime object.

```py
import time
from datetime import datetime

tm = time.time()

print(tm)

dt = str(tm).split('.')

print(dt)

timestamp = float(dt[0] + '.' + dt[1][:3]) 

dt_object = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)

print(dt_object)
```

This prints for example:

```
tm : 1638463260.919723

dt : ['1638463260', '919723']
```

and

```
dd_object : 2021-12-02 17:41:00.919000
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works:

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.now()
print(f"{dt:%Y/%m/%dT%H:%M:%S}.{f'{dt:%f}'[:3]}")
```

Hope I help.

Comment: Thanks but that will result in a string, and I need a datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide nanoseconds by 1000000000 to get seconds and by 1000000 to get milliseconds.

Here is some code that will get nanoseconds:

```
tim = time.time_ns()
```

You can then combine the output of this with the rest of the format. Probably not the cleanest solution but it should work.

Comment: Note: dividing by 1_000_000 you may lose precision. Floats have 15 digit precision.